# Set session with HashTable data type

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

there is a issue with session in ASP.NET Core 1.1

In WebForm, not in ASP.NET Core 1.1, I've used session as

```
Hashtable data = new Hashtable();
Session.Add("ket", data);
```

. Now I'm trying to make it in ASP.NET Core 1.1. But there are only three method for Session

```
void ISession.Set(string key, byte[] value);
void ISession.SetInt32(string key, int value);
void ISession.SetString(string key, string value);
```

How can I set session with HashTable data type like

```
Hashtable data = new Hashtable();
HttpContext.Session.Set("key", data);
```

in ASP.NET Core 1.1??

Comment: See: https://andrewlock.net/an-introduction-to-session-storage-in-asp-net-core/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Meaning Asp.net core doesn't support storing object in session anymore. Or to be more correct, they don't auto serialize the object for you anymore.

In this case you can serialize it to JSON, and store it as String.

```
var _data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
context.Session.SetString("key", _data);
```

To retrieve the hash:

```
var _data = _context.Session.GetString("key");
Hashtable retrieveData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Hashtable>(retrieveData);
```